# Unable to load a file within a software using remote desktop connection

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, remote-desktop, remote, sd-card

I was recently working with Windows Remote desktop connection. The local machine is windows 7 and the remote machine is windows 8. The connection was successful.

I have a software installed on the remote machine. For some reason I wanted to use this software on the remote machine using the remote desktop connection from a local machine. The software on the remote machine will load a database file from the SD card that is connected to local machine.

**Problem**: When I connect to the remote machine using Remote desktop connection, the software is able to locate the file on the SD card but when I load it the software stops responding. However when I copy the file from the SD card to some place on the remote machine and then when I load the file it gets loaded without any problems. I am not sure if this is a software's problem or is it a RDP's problem. I have contacted the software's technical support but as usual hasn't received any response yet.

Did some one had similar kind of experiences before? Is this a software issue or RDP's issue?

**Note**: The SD is detected by the remote machine and I am able to browse the files too.

Comment: Howdy, welcome to SU.  Can you stop with the "Level: beginner" stuff?   It adds nothing to your question, and if they are really "Beginner" problems, then there should be no need for you to ask for help. ;)

Comment: Sorry for that. I wouldn't repeat that. It is just a habit from StackOverflow. I used that line there to mention that I am new to a particular programming language so that even if I ask something very basic at least some one would point me out rather than flagging the question. :)

Comment: Since I was the only one that answered, I will suggest that you re-word the question and the steps you took in trying to solve it.  Your description is at best very difficult to follow.

Comment: @MikeAWood Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my question. I hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to monitor local file usage and locks on both the local and remote stations.  Apps like filemon and/or procmon from Systernals might shed some light on the subject.  The only time I have seen issues where there were file problems were on highly latent connections with multi MB sized MDB files which are buggy even over a local connection due to file locking.  Given your files are so small, that is probably not the case.

Comment: No, this is not what I  asked. :) If you read my question once more you will notice that I already mentioned that I was able to browse files in SD card on the remote machine!

Comment: Except your question is so indirectly worded that is was impossible to figure out what was able to read where.  I just re-read it and I still don't completely follow what works where.  Anyways, there are some issues with file locks over RDP accessible drives that show up on latent connections.  We used to see this all the time of laptops with integrated 3G connections and large MDB files. My suggestion isn't to access them over the RDP session, but maybe script copy process so the files are loaded locally by the app you are using.. If the file is large, it might take a while to load otherwise.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question. Also, the file in my case is in KB.

Comment: You might try filemon from systernals on both the local and remote and see what might be locking the file (assuming that is what it is).  I didn't have this problem with KB sized files.  Are you opening the file locally and remotely at the same time?  I suspect this is an issue with your software, other the large files over latent connections, typically the drive mapping works pretty reliably..

Comment: These are good suggestions. I'll try them later and let you know. Please add this info to your answer as well. If everything worked out then I'll able to accept your answer. Thanks :)